# css is not working on dynamicaly loaded header file in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

i'm working on jquery mobile single page application so all my page are in index.php with different id's.my problem is that when i tried to make a single header to all pages then on adding that header file into all pages the css of header is not working.
i have used that header in my first page in index.html thats working fine but when i called it from outside its not working properly.

Here is my Header file namd as appheader.html:

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme="p" data-position="fixed">
        <h1></h1>
        <a href="#left-panel" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext" data-role="button">Menu</a>
    </div>

<a data-theme="d" data-corners="false" data-role="button" href="#"> <img src="images/pearl-logo.png" alt="rss" style="display: block; margin: 1.5em auto;"></a>

<div data-role="panel" id="left-panel"  data-position="left" data-display="push" data-dismissible="true" data-theme="c">
<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="d" data-divider-theme="d" data-icon="false" data-global-nav="docs" class="jqm-list">
            <li data-role="list-divider">LINKS</li>
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#20years">20 Years</a></li>
            <li><a href="#courses">Courses</a></li>
            <li><a href="#events">Fun @ Pearl</a></li>
            <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#noida">Noida</a></li>
            <li><a href="#jaipur">Jaipur</a></li>
            <li><a href="#delhi">Delhi</a></li>
            <li><img src="images/pearl-logo.png"></li>
</ul>       
</div>
```

Here is jquery to add this page in my index.html having differnt pages combined with id's:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {

        $('[data-role=page]').one('pagebeforeshow', function (event, ui) {
       $("#" + event.target.id).find("[data-role=appheader]").load("appheader.html", function(){
         //$("#" + event.target.id).find("[data-role=panel]").trigger("pagecreate");
         // refresh the page again
        //   alert('ok');
         $("#" + event.target.id).trigger("create"); 
           });
        }); 

});

</script>
```

Here is how i call it in my all pages inside index.html:

```
<div data-role="page" id="20years" data-title="20years" data-url="20years"> 
<div data-role="appheader"></div>
  <div data-role="content">
</div>
</div>
```

The slider working fine when used in index.html but when called as a seperate file its not woking.

another qustion is how can i make this header panel swipe as my all pages having different id's.i just make it work on one of my page having id home :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).on( "pageinit", "#home", function() {
    $( document ).on( "swipeleft swiperight", "#home", function( e ) {
        // We check if there is no open panel on the page because otherwise
        // a swipe to close the left panel would also open the right panel (and v.v.).
        // We do this by checking the data that the framework stores on the page element (panel: open).
        if ( $.mobile.activePage.jqmData( "panel" ) !== "open" ) {
            if ( e.type === "swipeleft"  ) {
                $( "#right-panel" ).panel( "open" );
            } else if ( e.type === "swiperight" ) {
                $( "#left-panel" ).panel( "open" );
            }
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

how can i call my another pages in this jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing

`$("#" + event.target.id).trigger("create");`

with

`$("#" + event.target.id).trigger("pagecreate");`

Comment: @ DGS: hey bro can u plz tell me that how can i use swipe in different pages as my all pages are in index.html page with different id's. i have done this to make it work for my one page having id home.the code is added above in my qustion i just edit my question

Comment: anybody is there to help.